# magento zoomed images blurry in safari

Tags: css, magento, safari, image-scaling, image-size

I'm having a problem with magento product images that are blurry when viewed in safari, but display fine in firefox.

Specifically, when you zoom in on the product, the image is very distorted in safari even though I'm using significantly larger product images than what the browser is trying to display.

Here is an example: http://www.ktmbikeindustries.com/index.php/mountain-bikes/hardtails/carbon-29/myroon-29-prestige-2-f-22-s-xtr-263.html

[image]

What could be causing the blurry display in safari?  Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the effect you are referring to?

Comment: My reputation is too low to add an image on stack overflow, but here's a link to a screenshot: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2ccoscy&s=8#.VgrTVYt9cso